# On OptimisticLockException: version is set to newest value

Tags: java, hibernate, optimistic-locking

I'm using optimistic locking in Hibernate (via `@Version` for version-attribute of my bean). Therefore on conflicting changes the `OptimisticLockException` is thrown.

But - what I didn't expect: when this exception is thrown, the version attribute of my bean is automatically set to the actual (database) value while the other attributes have still the old values. So if I make an update to this object a second time, no `OptimisticLockException` is thrown anymore (as the version does not differ any more) and the data in this object overwrites the database state.

Is this expected behaviour?

EDIT:

MyBean:

```
@Entity
@Table(schema = "my_schema", name = "my_bean")
public class MyBean {
    ...
    @Version
    @Column(name = "version")
    private int version;
    ...
}
```

Read:

```
CriteriaQuery<MyBean> criteriaQuery = (CriteriaQuery<MyBean>)criteriaBuilder.createQuery(MyBean.class);
Root<MyBean> root = criteriaQuery.from(MyBean.class);
Expression<Integer> expr = (Expression<Integer>)root.get(MyBean_.id);
criteriaQuery.where(criteriaBuilder.equal(expr, 1));
Query q = currentSession.createQuery(criteriaQuery);
MyBean myBean = (MyBean)q.getResultList().get(0);

System.out.println("Version after read:" + myBean.getVersion();
```

Write:

```
System.out.println("Version before update:" + myBean.getVersion();

try {
    myBean.setText("test");
    transaction = session.beginTransaction();
    session.update(myBean);
    transaction.commit();
}
catch (Exception exc) {
    exc.printStackTrace();
    transaction.rollback;
    session.close();
}

System.out.println("Version after update:" + myBean.getVersion();
```

Logging:

```
Process 1: "Version after read: 1"
Process 2: "Version after read: 1"

Process 1: "Version before update: 1"
Process 1: "Version after update: 2"

Process 2: "Version before update: 1"
    javax.persistence.OptimisticLockException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.wrapStaleStateException(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:214) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.12.Final.jar:5.2.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:88) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.12.Final.jar:5.2.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:157) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.12.Final.jar:5.2.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:164) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.12.Final.jar:5.2.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1443) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.12.Final.jar:5.2.12.Final]

Process 2: "Version after update: 2"
```

Comment: i tried it in a example but for me the version stays after exception on the old version value. (I guess that is your expected behavior?) Can you maybe post some code.

Comment: @pL4Gu33 I've added the basic steps of my code and a logging

Comment: I've tried to reproduce it, but it doesn't work. Its really strange. I used your code and get the same version for before/after. I used your hibernate version, too. Sorry i dont know whats going on in your example :/

Answer (score 0):

No this is not expected behavior..Version should not increment in case of `OptimisticLockException`.Please check whether any linked child entity gets updated ,but during Parent entity updation `OptimisticLockException` occurs or vice versa.